# Python PyQt5 passing class variables without re-opening window

Tags: python, class, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I want to pass a variable to my main window from a different class without reopening my main window. this is my current code, but it keeps re-opening the window.

```py
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import *
import sys
class HoverButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        QPushButton.__init__(self, name, parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print (self.name)
        self.mm = MainMenu()
        self.mm.lastHoverdButton = self.name
class MainMenu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        # super().__init__()
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lastHoverdButton = ''
        self.btnOpen = HoverButton('Hello World', self)
        self.btnOpen.move(100,100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainMenu()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My expected result, would be to not re-open the main window, and still get variable updated somehow. I assume you could somehow use Threads? I'm not sure how you would do this.

Comment: You don’t need self.mm = MainMenu() as you already have self.parent. (Is that correct self.parent?)

Comment: 1) remove `self.mm = MainMenu()
        self.mm.lastHoverdButton = self.name` 2) add `self.parent().lastHoverdButton = self.name`

Comment: I had got it working by making a separate variable outside of all classes, and making it global. I know its not good practice, but if it works, don't touch it.